# Why Mongoid::Criteria could use the object's as_json?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I am new to RoR and facing problem using Mongoid.
The code was written by someone else, but I need to do some modifications.
Here's the code in model:

```
class AClass
  include Mongoid::Document  
  field :data, type: String  
  ...  
  scope ...  

  def self.search(params) 
    AClass.only(...)# return a Criteria Object
  end

  def as_json(options={})
    ...
  end

end
```

And the code in controller:

```
def index
  @res = AClass.search(query_params) # @res is a Criteria Object
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: @res.as_json(format: params[:format], 
                                            path: request.env['ORIGINAL_FULLPATH']) } # why AClass's as_json is called
    format.xml  { render xml: @res.as_json(format: params[:format],
                                           path: request.env['ORIGINAL_FULLPATH']).
                                           to_xml(root: "root",
                                                  camelize: true) }
    format.html  
  end  
end
```

I have two questions:

1. I found `only` method belongs to `Mongoid::Criteria` and `Mongoid::Document` module does not contain the `Criteria` Class. Only `Mongoid::Document` is included in the code above. Why the `only` could be called in `self.search`?
2. I found that the returned value of Only is `Mongoid::Criteria`. However, when I request json data, the `@res.as_json` could call the `AClass`'s `as_json` method. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. I found only method belongs to `Mongoid::Criteria` and `Mongoid::Document` module does not contain the `Criteria` Class. Only
>      `Mongoid::Document` is included in the code above. Why the only could be
>      called in `self.search`?

The `only` method can be found in [Mongoid::Criteria::Queryable::Optional](https://github.com/mongodb/mongoid/blob/master/lib/mongoid/criteria/queryable/optional.rb#L146) which is delegated to via [Mongoid::Document](https://github.com/mongodb/mongoid/blob/master/lib/mongoid/document.rb) (feel free to dig around the code).

> 2. I found that the returned value of `only` is `Mongoid::Criteria`. However, when I request json data, the `@res.as_json` could call the
>      `AClass`'s `as_json` method. Why?

`Mongoid::Criteria#as_json` calls `as_json` on the underlying documents collection which calls `as_json` on each underlying document:

[mongoid/criteria.rb](https://github.com/mongodb/mongoid/blob/master/lib/mongoid/criteria.rb#L63):

```
# Needed to properly get a criteria back as json
#
# @example Get the criteria as json.
#   Person.where(:title => "Sir").as_json
#
# @param [ Hash ] options Options to pass through to the serializer.
#
# @return [ String ] The JSON string.
def as_json(options = nil)
  entries.as_json(options)
end
```